# Can participial adjectives ever include any associated clauses, like objects, in attributive use?

Tags: adjectives

This is correct:

> The *engaging*, beautiful lady was wearing red.
>
> The *engaged*, beautiful lady was wearing red.

But adding an object or a prepositional clause to *engaging/engaged*, I think, makes it invalid in attributive use:

> The *engaging **me***, beautiful lady was wearing red.
>
> The *engaged **by me***, beautiful lady was wearing red.

I speak several other languages, and know that, for example, in Russian the equivalent phrase is perfectly correct. But it looks like English grammar is more limiting in that regard. When I google phrases like that I don't get any hits in books.

My question is: is adding clauses like this to adjectives always invalid in attributive use, or are there some exceptions?

Comment: It would have to be "I, the engaging, beautiful lady, was wearing red." *Engaged*, by the way, means *betrothed*.

Comment: Sorry, I my choice of example is probably poor. I meant more like *engage in conversation*.

Comment: In your examples, does *me* refer to the speaker? (By that, I mean another person.)

Comment: Yes, to the speaker.

Comment: So the meaning of the last example is "The beautiful lady engaged in conversation with me was wearing red."?

Comment: This is close to what was intended. To me the meaning is clear from the beginning, because I am used to understanding such constructs in another language.

Comment: It's not just participle adjectives that resist this sort of usage when used before the noun. The scared-of-snakes youth, an eager-for-his-holidays teacher, a shocked-by-the-news woman, the proud-of-their-daughter parents, the fond-of-dogs brigade ... All of these are non-standard usages (though they are sometimes used in tongue-in-cheek writing). / What some term 'transitive adjectives' are mentioned at [The Grammar Book: Chapter 3, Part 1, slide 9)](http://www.slideboom.com/presentations/31680/The-Grammar-Book,-Chapter-3,-Part-1).

Comment: 'The beautiful lady engaged by me was wearing red.' uses 'engaged' as a past participle (with whiz-deletion from a passive construction) rather than an adjective. Although the form of 'engaged' in 'The beautiful lady engaged in conversation with me was wearing red.' is the adjective.

Comment: It's a word order thing, that wouldn't occur in Russian. Only one-word modifiers can precede the noun; modifiers of more than one word, including participial clauses and relative clauses, must follow the noun. So you can say _the beautiful lady engaging me/engaged by me_, but not, as you point out,  *_the beautiful engaging me lady_.